# Unable to send using send_keys python selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, servicenow

> Hi All,
>
> I'm trying to send some text data using send_keys in the search box as
>   attached in the image but unable to send it on. Gives me error.
>   Currently the focus is on "Short description" and it needs to be moved
>   to search box and needs to be sent Tried sending the text info using
>   xpath but doen't helps. The 'Id' keeps changing so it also doen't
>   helps me.

[search box is the textbox where im trying to send the text data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrNQ6.png)

> Below is the elemnet that i got after copying the element

```
<input id="5e3dc64a2f3010109e9a3c96f699b632_text" placeholder="Search" class="form-control" style="width: 150px;" name="5e3dc64a2f3010109e9a3c96f699b632_text" aria-describedby="5e3dc64a2f3010109e9a3c96f699b632_describedby">
```

> Below is the xpath:

```
//*[@id="5e3dc64a2f3010109e9a3c96f699b632_text"]
```

> Below is part of code i'm using to send

```
search_box = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='form-control']")
search_box.click()
search_box.send_keys("Unable to access the shared folder")
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem could be presence of other elements which share the same class name.
Steps to debug:
You can try:

```
search_box.click()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```

During the wait, observe if the search box gets highlighted. If not, selenium probably is unable to locate the webElement and presence of multiple web elements which share the same class name could be the problem.